# X11 Retrieve Topmost Window According To An Area Position

Tags: c, x11, xlib

I ma currently looking retrieve the window present at a certain position. I've already retrieved the list of windows but I'm not sure how to proceed to retrieve the topmost one.

Here is what I have accomplished so far (contains a testing main):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xatom.h>

typedef struct
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int w;
    int h;
} area_coords_t;

static inline Window get_toplevel_parent(Display * display, Window window)
{
    Window parent;
    Window root;
    Window * children;
    unsigned int num_children;

    while (1) {
        if (0 == XQueryTree(display, window, &root, &parent, &children, &num_children)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "XQueryTree error\n");
            abort(); //change to whatever error handling you prefer
        }
        if (children) { //must test for null
            XFree(children);
        }
        if (window == root || parent == root) {
            return window;
        }
        else {
            window = parent;
        }
    }
}

static inline void print_windows(Display *display, area_coords_t *area)
{
    Window *list;
    Window toplevel;
    Atom prop = XInternAtom(display, "_NET_CLIENT_LIST",False);
    Atom type;
    unsigned long len;
    XWindowAttributes attr;

    if (XGetWindowProperty(display, XDefaultRootWindow(display), prop,
        0, 1024, False, XA_WINDOW, &type, &(int) { 0 }, &len, &(unsigned long) { 0 }, (unsigned char **) &list) != Success)
        return;
    for (unsigned long it = 0; it < len; ++it)
    {
        toplevel = get_toplevel_parent(display, list[it]);
        XGetWindowAttributes(display, toplevel, &attr);
        /* Retrieve only windows in the given area */
        //if (area->x >= attr.x && area->x <= attr.x + attr.width && area->y >= attr.y && area->y <= attr.y + attr.height)
        printf("%dx%dx%dx%d\n", attr.x, attr.y, attr.width, attr.height);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    Display *display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    /* Should retrieve a window occupying at least a pixel at of the bottom right part of the screen of a 1920x1080 screen */
    area_coords_t coords = { 1920 / 2, 1080 / 2, 1920 / 2, 1080 / 2 };

    print_windows(display, &coords);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem with that is the windows do not seem to be ordered.

How can I retrieve the topmost window to ensure I get the appropriate window for a given position ?

Comment: 1. Save all window attributes into allocated array of structures. 2. Sort it. 3. Get the first array member.

Comment: @KamilCuk Sorting it is exacly what I am struggling with. What attribute shall I sort it with ?

Comment: Is there a Z-Plane attribute that you can sort on?  Z-plane == 0 is the last one drawn, so it will be on top.

Comment: @ryyker Doesn't look like it. The Attribute structure can be found here: https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window-information/XGetWindowAttributes.html ; the only thing that looked interesting was the `depth` field, but it always seems to be either 24 or 32.

Comment: I just _[read this about windows managers in x11](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40259066/645128)_.  It seems pretty spartan.  I think depth field may have to do with color depth.

Comment: Ah, ye effectively. Unfortunately I am not creating a window manager, there is already one setup. I only wish to retrieve the topmost window at a location for already built windows. I use X11 because I need to draw some shapes anywhere on the screen without associating it a window, but maybe am I using the wrong library ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Put differently: Why are you starting from _NET_CLIENT_LIST? Do you only want toplevel windows as defined by ICCCM (i.e. windows actually managed by the WM), or any windows? I am asking, because I was going to suggest you use XQueryTree on the root window. That returns the list of children in sorted order. Alternatively, you might want to use `_NET_CLIENT_LIST_STACKING` instead of `_NET_CLIENT_LIST`. Depending on what you really want, I can turn the relevant part of this into an answer.

Comment: What I am looking for is the dimensions of the visible window. From what I've seen, `_NET_CLIENT_LIST` gives some inner window with relative `x` and `y` position. The `_NET_CLIENT_LIST_STACKING` looks to be what I am looking for, the topmost always seem to be the last index. One issue with it though: it does not display windows created after the one started after the program. What I am trying to do: retrieve the positions and dimensions of the window I am clicking on.

Answer (score 1):

[`XQueryTree()`](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window-information/XQueryTree.html) returns the windows in stacking order, topmost last.

> **Description**
>
> The `XQueryTree()` function returns the root ID, the parent window ID,
>   a pointer to the list of children windows (`NULL` when there are no
>   children), and the number of children in the list for the specified
>   window. **The children are listed in current stacking order, from
>   bottommost (first) to topmost (last).** `XQueryTree()` returns zero if
>   it fails and nonzero if it succeeds. To free a non-`NULL` children
>   list when it is no longer needed, use `XFree()`.

I've never used the call for this purpose, and haven't done direct X11 programming in years, but from that I'd imagine you could just loop through the returned list from querying the root window and save the window ID of any window covering your desired location to the same variable every time.  Since the last one found covering that location is the topmost (at least it was when you made the call...), that would be the window ID of the visible window at that location.