# How to change windows order via the command line on kubuntu?

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I am doing Mac-like 3-finger window switching to go to the previous or next opened Application.

I am getting the opened windows list via

```
xprop -root | grep "NET_CLIENT_LIST_STACKING(WINDOW)"
```

and I use

```
wmctrl -a <window_id> -i
```

to focus a window.

My problem is that switching to previous window is actually swapping the latest window and previous one.

Imagine I have 3 running apps, e.g.:

- Chrome 1
- PyCharm 2
- Dolphin 3 (currently opened)

If i try to focus the previous window (PyCharm) with

```
wmctrl -a 2 -i
```

the new order looks like

- Chrome 1
- Dolphin 3
- PyCharm 2

If I again try to focus the previous window, I expect to focus Chrome, but Dolphin will be focused instead. So right now, I am doing `wmctrl -a` for every window from bottom to top except the currently focused window.

I want somehow to use some commands to change order, so that I do not have to focus every opened window.

Comment: I can't understand what you mean, but you may want to check out `xdotool` package.

Comment: I need to change Z-order of opened window.

Comment: According to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40257320/how-to-define-window-stacking-orde the only way to solve my problem is to use `wmctrl -a` on every opened window to reoder them properly. :(